# Automatically link words using PHP

Tags: php

I have thousands of PHP pages which have a header and footer included using php, like

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?> //STATIC CONTENT HERE  <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

I want to implement auto keyword linking for certain keywords in the static text. But I can only add PHP codes to my header or footer files.

Comment: Please define what you mean by *"auto keyword linking"* ... Do you mean you want to replace all occurrences of certain words with a link pointing to a specific address for that word?

Comment: @rdlowrey yes, thats what I am looking for. The problem is the Static Content is not in a variable/string. Its purely static.

Comment: thousands? really? well, if you're not prepared to modify those files at all, then I think you need to consider using a javascript to modify the output in the browser... doubt there's anything you can do in PHP

Comment: The main idea behind this SEO. Googel does not consider links created using javascript, does it? or can i use jquery?

Comment: I suppose you could use PHP to get the current file name and hence get the file's contents, and then do the keyword filtering (e.g. apples -> <a href="www.apples.com">apples</a>) on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a complex operation. The steps:

1. Get all the files whose words you want to replace ([`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php))
2. Specify an array (or arrays) for the "find" and "replace" criteria
3. Iterate over the files returned by `glob` replacing the text as you go ([`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php))
4. Write the new text ([`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

This sample code replaces all words in the `$words` array with a link to `http://www.wordlink.com/<yourword>`. If you need a different link for each word you'll need to specify `$replace` as an array using `$1` where you want the searched word to appear in the replacement (and change `$replace` in the regex to `$replace[$i]`).

Also, the `glob` function below looks for all html files in the specified `$filesDir` directory. If you need something different you're going to have to manually edit the `glob` path yourself. Finally, the regular expression used only replaces whole words. i.e. if you wanted to replace the word *super*, the word *superman* will not have the word *super* replaced in the middle.

Oh, and the replace is **NOT** case sensitive as per the `i` modifier at the end of the pattern.

```
// specify where your static html files live
$filesDir = '/path/to/my/html/files/';

// specify where to save your updated files
$newDir   = '/location/of/new/files/';

// get an array of all the static html files in $filesDir
$fileList = glob("$filesDir/*.html");

$words    = array('super', 'awesome');
$replace  = '<a href="http://www.wordlink.com/$1">$1</a>';

// iterate over the html files.
for ($i=0; $i < count($fileList); $i++) {
  $filePath = $filesDir . $fileList[$i];
  $newPath  = $newDir . $fileList[$i];
  
  $html     = file_get_contents($filePath);
  $pattern  = '#\b(' . str_replace('#', '\#', $words[$i]) . ')\b#i';
  $html     = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);
  file_put_contents($newPath, $html);
  echo "$newpath file written\n";
}
```

Obviously, you need write-access to the new folder location. I would not recommend overwriting your original files. Translation:

### Always backup before doing anything crazy.

P.S. the regexes are not UTF-8 safe, so if you're dealing with international characters you'll need to edit the regex pattern as well.

P.P.S. I'm really being kind here because SO is **not** a code-for-free site. Don't even think about commenting something like "it doesn't work" when I try it :) If it doesn't fit your specifications, feel free to peruse the php manual for the functions involved.

Comment: Its too complex for me.. and I know SO is not a code for free site. Its just an assist for small webmasters like me :) I am really grateful for you to have taken time and written that code for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sam Still not all is lost! Did you tried my solution? Please inform a little more about the size of your static files. If they are small my snippet will do exactly what you want. Even (depending of keyword's nature) we could adapted it to use just `str_replace` to be nice with your server. Indeed I would do it in that way. And, to be clear, only if you really need dynamic replacements (at run time).

Comment: @NomikOS But you said that the code was inefficient. Will that cause heavy server load? Will it affect Page Speed? The pages might be small, averaging 20kb per page. An example page is http://www.amitash.com/n/01181011.php

Comment: @Sam Will using PHP regexes to replace text on every page load work for this problem? Yes. If you have only a few page loads each day you'll never notice a thing performance-wise. However, if you achieve any real level of traffic this is in no way a tenable solution. Most times there are right and wrong ways to tackle a problem. Wasting computation to repeatedly perform the same operation over and over when it can be accomplished once is never a desirable solution.

Comment: @rdlowrey I understand what you say. I am now trying to manually insert links, if not all pages, atleast the key ones. Seriously, once again, I am so grateful for you and NomikOS to have taken so much time into this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an idea. I did a quick test and seems works...

```
<?php

include("header.php");
ob_start();

?>

//STATIC CONTENT HERE

<?php

$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// now you have all your STATIC CONTENT HERE into $contents var
// so you can use preg_replace on it to add your links

echo $contents_with_my_links;

include("footer.php");
?>
```

Indeed you should add this code to your current header/footer files.

---

OK. Its just an idea that solves the problem. As `rdlowrey` said this may be inefficient, but if you need replace keywords dynamically (with database based link, for instance) then this could be a good solution...

Comment: While this will work, it's horribly inefficient to be running regexes on every page load to change static content ...

Comment: @rdlowrey I think that Sam wants add links dynamically (**But I can only add PHP codes to my header or footer files.**). Otherwise we could use a tool like `sed` to updates their files.

Comment: Ah I see ... I guess I didn't consider that because it's a terrible idea to attempt this on a per-page-load basis. The `sed` idea on the other hand is a good one if there are a small number of words to replace or he's capable of putting together a shell script.

Comment: @Sam Sam specifically say **The problem is the Static Content is not in a variable/string. Its purely static** My solution do that: put all static content in a variable to play with it as you need. And his goal is to add links dynamically (**Automatically link words using PHP**) (links including something like userid or current time, for instance). Sam do not ask for "automatically update" their files to replace `static words` for `static links`. Besides if the links change just a little you should repeat the whole process again, which is very inefficient too.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Your solution works. **However**, I'm trying to make it clear that it should not be implemented in the real world. Checking an entire page of static content with regexes to replace text EVERY time that page is loaded is **NOT** an efficient solution. If you only replace the text one time it makes no difference how fast the code runs. If you need it dynamically replaced, that is what javascript is for. If javascript is not an option, you shouldn't replace the text every time with PHP. It is not scalable.

Comment: @rdlowrey Hi again. Let's stay something clear: I understand what you say too, but you are out of scope. You didn't responded to the question asked. You talked about make **static replacements** And that is not the issue here. The scenario presented by the user is very common (make text replacement at runtime) and the ONLY solution for that is do it EACH TIME that page is loaded. Besides checking again what Sam said **Googel does not consider links created using javascript, does it?**. So Javascript is not a solution, which to be honest could be very inefficient for the client. Peace colleague

Comment: But because (as stated) *"The main idea behind this SEO. Googel does not consider links created using javascript, does it? or can i use jquery?"* the only way to solve the problem for SEO is to replace the text in the static files, either at each page load or at a single point before page loads. Ergo, I did answer the question (note the upvotes and the check) and am simply pointing out to any future passersby who don't understand the inefficiency of regex on a large scale per-page-load that they shouldn't implement this dynamically. I think we're probably saying the same thing here :)

Comment: @rdlowrey _I think we're probably saying the same thing here_ That's for sure my friend. Only one more statement. The question started **I have thousands of PHP pages which have a header and footer included using php**. That it is a **real life fact**. Those files exist as they are and if you need make dynamic replacements then you must do it at runtime. Of course if we could start from the beginning it should be another history. And Yes, I see your upvotes, WHAT ENVY! LOL. See us...